# How to add a new drop target after initializing drag drop sources

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

How can I add new  drop target after initializing drag drop sources. I tried to add it to the source and then calling init on the new targets. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but I just thought I'd let you know that I ended up pulling in jQuery and jQuery UI for drag & drop and sorting. I found the drag & drop stuff that ships with the `goog.ui` package is too limited and not very flexible. Not that the one in jQuery UI isn't limited and flexible, but at least it behaves in a more fluid and smooth way.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, you don't need to init the source again. Just init the new targets and add the event handlers.